# Problems writing to file android

Tags: android, file, input

I'm trying to save some data to A file in android, I'm using herefor the internal storage of the android system. I looked it up on the developers guide of android and I came to this.

```
String FILENAME = "LangFile";
                String data ="NL";
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                fos.write(data.getBytes());
                fos.close();
```

This is how I save it to the file.

```
String FILENAME = "LangFile";
        String languege = "lang";
        FileInputStream fos = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        fos.read(languege.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        if(languege=="NL"){
            newgame.setText(R.string.dutchgames);
            stats.setText(R.string.duthstats);
        }
```

This is how I read from the same file, but if I run it it just gives an empty button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare strings using `==`, in fact you need to use either `equals` or `equalsIgnoreCase` methods. You also need to tweak your reading logic a little. Change your code as below:

```
FileInputStream fos = openFileInput(FILENAME);
byte[] b = new byte[2]; //since lang-prefix should have at least length 2
fos.read(b);
fos.close();

if(new String(b).equalsIgnoreCase("NZ")){
     newgame.setText(R.string.dutchgames);
     stats.setText(R.string.duthstats);
}
```

Comment: I tryed it on that way but it won't work still only the empty buttons

Comment: Your file reading logic is suspicious to me. Check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

did you add the permission to write the internal storage?

```
  <uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in your manifest.xml file

Comment: Where do I place this line in the manifest between the aplication or just above this. And is it the same for the internal storage?

Comment: It just stays the same, only empthy buttons

Answer (score 0):

```
if(languege=="NL"){
            newgame.setText(R.string.dutchgames);
            stats.setText(R.string.duthstats);
        }
```

if condition is blocking from reading bytes from file. As == matches object references not their contents.